# Keyboard disappearing when input on focus - mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code and everything works good, but when I open my search bar on mobile and click on input field, my keyboard opens and closes, I found that window.resize is the problem, but I haven't found any fixes for this, what should I do?

```
function appendSearchBar() {
    if($(window).width() <= 769){
        $('.search-bar').appendTo('.mobile-toolbar .global-search');
    } else {
        $('.search-bar').appendTo('.header-toolbar-nav .global-search');
    }
}
$(window).resize(function() {
    appendSearchBar();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `appendTo` the element is detach and re-attached to the DOM and thus loses focus.

You should only append if it is not where you want it.

```js
let inMobile;

function appendSearchBar(firstTime) {
  const windowWidth = $(window).width();

  if (windowWidth <= 769 && (!inMobile || firstTime)) {
    inMobile = true;
    $('.search-bar').appendTo('.mobile-toolbar .global-search');
  }
  if (windowWidth > 769 && (inMobile || firstTime)) {
    inMobile = false;
    $('.search-bar').appendTo('.header-toolbar-nav .global-search');
  }

  $(window).resize(function() {
    appendSearchBar();
  });

  appendSearchBar(true);
```